# AWS S3 CLI ls list directories without prefix into an array (and where clause)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

From EC2 console terminal, I am trying to list a part of an S3 bucket directory names into an array excluding a prefix "date=" but cannot figure out a complete solution.

I've already tried the following code and getting close:

```
origin="bucket/path/to/my/directory/" 
for path in $(aws s3 ls $origin --profile crossaccount --recursive | awk '{print $4}'); 
do echo "$path"; done
```

**note**: directory contains multiple directories like /date=YYYYMMDD/ and all I want to be returned into an array is the YYYYMMDD where YYYYMMDD is >= a certain value.

I expect the output to be an array:

```
YYYYMMDD, YYYYMMDD, YYYYMMDD
```

actual result is:

```
path/to/my/directory/date=YYYYMMDD/file#1
path/to/my/directory/date=YYYYMMDD/file#2
path/to/my/directory/date=YYYYMMDD/file#3
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html

Comment: Would you be willing to use Python, or does this have to be done in shell?

Answer (score 0):

```
path="bucket/path/to/my/directory/date="
for i in $(aws s3 ls $path --profile crossaccount --recursive | awk -F'[=/]' '{if($6>20190000)print $6}');
do python3.6 my_python_program.py $i; done
```

I used awk. In the bracket are the column delimiters =/, and $6 is the 6th column after the directory full name has been delimited. It gave me the date I needed to feed into my python program.